# protected access modifiers in .net

Tags: c#, protected, access-modifiers

i created an application depicting the protected access modifiers, using the sample provided on `MSDN` site, but it seems to be error prone, below is the code i am using:

[image: Protected Access Modifier in c#]

and below is the sample from MSDN site:

[image: MSDN Reference for Protected Access Modifiers]

Comment: you're posting an image of the code??

Comment: @vulkanino It would be tolerable if it had big red freehand circles.

Comment: I'm behind a firewall that blocks SE images.. I can't see the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `AccessModifiersCSharp` class which is where `Main` is defined does not inherit from `Class1`, so has no access to its `protected` members.

You *can* access `Method1` from your `Class2` as it does inherit from `Class1`.

The difference between your code and the MSDN code is that class `B` that contains `Main` inherits directly from `A`.

Answer (score 0):

protected members of class A can only be accessed from classes derived from A.

This means Class2 can access Method1(), but not AccessModifiersCSharp

see [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bcd5672a%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

If you want your code to compile, you need to declare Method1() as public or internal.

Answer (score 0):

Put the Main() method **inside** Class2 instead of the class AccessModifiersCSharp! The AccessModifiersCSharp does not derive from Class1 and thus has no access to its protected members and methods.

Answer (score 0):

In the article that you referenced, Main is a method of B, which is why it has access to protected members of B, and, through inheritance, A's protected members.

Answer (score 0):

> A protected member is accessible from within the class in which it is
>   declared, and from within any class derived from the class that
>   declared this member

it's mean: you can access Methode1 in Class1 methods And Class2 Methods. and You can access Method2  only in Class2 methods.

Main() Method in AccessModifiersCSharp class. and only can access to public method of Class1 and Class2.